# How to model ACL structures in graphs using spring-data-neo4j (from the example provided in the neo4j docs)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

New to neo4j. I would like to implement an ACL structure using Spring-data-neo4j-4. I stumbled upon this ACL example [neo4j.com/docs/stable/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/examples-acl-structures-in-graphs.html) in the docs but I don't find it very intuitive to replicate this using Spring-data-neo4j-4.

Could some one please provide a brief example for implementing the example ACL graph structure using spring data neo4j?

Specifically... how to model the "SECURITY" and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data for Neo4j is based on OGM (Object-Graph Mapping), which is similar to Hybernate or other ORM libraries.

Than if you want to model Security from that article. It should be enough to create domain objects in SDN based on the model from the article.

Comment: Similar to hibernate but not exact. Mapping relationships is different. Hence why I created this question... and If it is so simple why does not a single IMPLEMENTED ACL example exist anywhere on a google search or stack overflow. As I stated in the question I would like to see an example specifically with how the "security" relationship is mapped with the permission flags (i.e "+r") with spring data neo4j. I don't think this is an unreasonable request.